# TypeScript AMD compilation and "barrel" modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, amd, intern

I'm trying to set up a Node.js + TypeScript project using [Intern](https://theintern.github.io/) for testing. Everything works fine when I compile the project using "commonjs" (which I do for the normal build); and TypeScript is equally happy when compiling for "amd", which is required by Intern. However, when passing the tests with `intern-client`, it complains about a couple of things:

First, imports from "index.ts" files (so-called "barrel" modules) won't work. My setup is something like this (everything in the same directory):

```
// index.ts
export { x } from './x'

// x.ts
export function x() {}

// x.test.ts
import { x } from '.' // "Error: Failed to load module ..."
```

In fact, the generated JavaScript code (for `x.test.ts`) looks something like this:

```
define(["require", "exports", "."], function (...) { ... })
```

And I'm not sure that AMD knows how to handle the `"."`.

The second issue happens under the same circumstances (TypeScript compiles happily, but `intern-client` complains). In summary, I get an error when doing:

```
import jsdom = require('jsdom')
```

Which I need to transform to:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom')
```

For Intern to be able to deal with it.

Here is the `tsconfig.json` file I use to compile the tests:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "amd",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "build/tests",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    }
}
```

And here is my `intern.js` configuration file, in case it helps:

```
define({
    suites: ['build/tests/**/*.test.js'],
    excludeInstrumentation: true,
    filterErrorStack: true
})
```

**Edit** (2017-05-03)

To help understand the issue, here is an excerpt of the directory tree of the project:

```
build
    tests // The compiled tests will end up here
src
    core
    utils
        x.ts
        x.test.ts
        // Other files, each containing a function that I would like to unit-test...
intern.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
...
```

Comment: Could you describe the file layout of your project? Also, where is the `import jsdom = require('jsdom')` coming from (i.e., why wasn't it transformed into an AMD dependency by the TS compiler)?

Comment: Barrels are an anti-pattern

Comment: @jason0x43 x.test.ts imports x from x.ts (really, from "."), which imports y from y.ts (again, from "."), which imports jsdom via "import jsdom = require('jsdom')". I'm most worried about the other issue anyways; I have the feeling if it gets solve, the second one might be gone as well.

Comment: @AluanHaddad And that is an anti-advice. Please, elaborate further or no one who doesn't already know about the matter will get your point.

Comment: Well, for one thing it is a NodeJS only convention. The ES Module loader that eventually will appear in browsers has no mention of using an index to resolve a an import of a directory. Furthermore, overreliance on so called "barrels" often indicates that a library is awkwardly structured. For example, this pattern was heavily used in the Angular 2 alpha/beta/rc cycle and its use was indicative of the lack of structuring in the framework, was part of the awful "XXXX_PROVIDERS" pattern. Not saying it is always bad but best to at least use `index` explicitly. Of course `NgModule` is even worse.

Comment: Its also not supported by RequireJS, SystemJS, or anything that is not node related.

Comment: I just happened to be watching this talk and remembered this post -- https://youtu.be/hO7mzO83N1Q?t=9m56s (from 9:56 till 11:44). The speaker advocates for using the index.js pattern as a mean for clearly stating which files in the folder are meant to be publicly used, and thus hiding other implementation details.It looks like a quite compelling reason to me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first issue, AMD's handling of an import like '.' is different than Node's. While both of them will map '.' to a package, Node uses a default module name of `index.js`, while AMD uses `main.js`. To get things working in an AMD loader, you'll need to first define a package for '.', and then tell the AMD loader what default module to use for that package. Given your project layout, you could configure Intern like this:

```
loaderOptions: {
  map: {
    // When a module in src/ references 'src/utils', redirect
    // it to 'utils'
    'src': {
      'src/utils': 'utils'
    }
  },

  packages: [
    // Define a package 'utils' with files in 'src/utils' that defaults
    // to the module index.js
    { name: 'utils', location: 'src/utils', main: 'index.js' }
  ]
}
```

Regarding the second issue, its not clear what the problem actually is. Import statements will be transpiled into `define` dependencies by TypeScript, so Intern should never be seeing them.

Comment: I've realized, thanks to you, that the "packages" in the "loaderOptions" must point to the compiled JavaScript, as opposed to the TypeScript source. How about I complete the directory tree picture on the question, you adapt the answer too, and then I select it as the good one for the case?